# customize the interface / view

Tags: custom-fields

I am starting with CiviCRM this week and a user asked to me: how to customize the contact summary view to add the 'Contributions tag' into the summay

I think I have to go to admin menu: Administer > Personnaliser les données et écrans > Préférences d'affichage, but I'm not sure

Thanks in advance for you help
Javier

Comment: Can you clarify?  Not sure what you mean by adding the "Contributions tag" to contact summary.  Maybe take a screenshot of the current setup and mark what you're trying to change.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your user does not see the contributions tab in the contact summary?

That can be because on the fact that the CiviContribute component is switched off (Administer>System Settings>Components).

It can also be because the tab is switched off for the contact summary (Administer>Customize Data and Screens>Display Preferences - then check the if Contributions is ticked in Viewing Contacts)

Comment: Could also be a CMS user permission?